# Showing $H_3\left (\mathbb{RP}^4\right ) = \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I previously took time to compute the homology classes for $\mathbb{RP}^2$ and $\mathbb{RP}^3$ with

$$
H_k\left (\mathbb{RP}^2\right ) \;\; =\;\; \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}, & \text{if} \; k =0 \\
\mathbb{Z}_2, & \text{if} \; k = 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \hspace{2pc} \text{and} \hspace{2pc}  H_k\left (\mathbb{RP}^3\right ) \;\; =\;\; \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}, & \text{if} \; k =0, 3 \\
\mathbb{Z}_2, & \text{if} \; k = 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

Now, for $\mathbb{RP}^4$, $H_0$ and $H_1$ are trivial to find while we can exploit the cell decomposition of $\mathbb{RP}^4$ as adjoining $\mathbb{RP}^3$ to the closed disk $D^4 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$.  Results about the homology of CW complexes shows that since $\mathbb{RP}^4$ consists of one 4-cell, then the homomorphism induced by the attaching map sends $H_3\left (\mathbb{S}^3\right ) \to H_3\left (\mathbb{RP}^3\right )$ and this map is the identity.  This forces us to have $H_4\left (\mathbb{RP}^4\right ) = 0$.

I'm well aware from looking online that $H_3\left (\mathbb{RP}^4\right ) = \mathbb{Z}_2$, but I'm unclear how to compute it.  I tried looking at a segment of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence:

$$
\ldots \to H_3\left (\mathbb{RP}^3\right )\oplus H_3\left (D^4\right ) \to H_3\left (\mathbb{RP}^4\right ) \to H_2\left(\mathbb{RP}^3\right ) \to \ldots
$$

but I don't see how this gets me closer to showing the result (obviously $D^4$ is contractible so $H_k(D^4) = 0$ for all $k>0$).  I'm new to homology and most of the tools I have at my disposal are Mayer-Vietoris, results about cell complexes, and not much beyond that.

Comment: For general case, see Example 2.42 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*.